# Where do we find SQL Server 2014 logs?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, logging

I am running into an issue when trying to start a service for SQL Server 2014 Express. Each time I try to manually start my server from the SQL Server Configuration Manager, I get an error message reporting

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other application error logs for details.

I started by looking at some posts on this and other forums for similar issues and the suggested fixes didn't solve my problem. I concluded that the error message I saw was intended as a catch-all message that describes any error that could happen. Furthermore, I concluded that I would need to consult the event logs in order to get any useful feedback on what the underlying issue is.

So I went into the service properties -> Advanced -> Dump Directory where it lead me to a collection of log files. However, the log files I saw in the directory came from a few days ago when I first set up the server. They contain some login attempts from a few days ago, but today's attempts to start the server do not have any matching logs in that location. My question is where can I find Logs for the server start up or what other tools can I use to track down what the actual issue is? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: click the `Start` button, then click `Run`, and type `eventvwr.msc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Event Viewer that you can find in the Control Panel. The SQL Server logs events to the Application log.